# Contract double execution problem (use of SafeMath is not the issue)

Tags: solidity

Lets say in solidity every time user `pay_in` to the contract we **+1** the number of contributors and everyone the person `withdrew` we'll **-1** the number of conterbuters.

Having made a contract that is doing just that, apparently if the user try to execute `withdrew` function quick enough they can get the number of conterbuters all the way to large number.

Wondering if there is any way to prevent this from happening.

**PLEASE NOTE:**

I am aware of overflow issue and the use of **Mathsafe** library. however using the mathsafe library in code is computationally expensive and its not going to help if user count can go from 100 to 97. providing one user execute the code 3 times before the completion of the first two transation. hence why i do not think this is a overflow problem.

**update: Here is the simplified librery functions**

```
/**
 * Deposit
**/
function deposit(Store storage self) public {
    require(msg.value > 0);
    address user = msg.sender;
    // we already have the user down as Contributor
    if(self.contributor[user].ether_in<=0)
        self.numContributors++;
    self.contributor[user].ether_in += msg.value;
    self.ether_in += msg.value;
}
/**
 * withdraw
**/
function withdraw(Store storage self) internal {
    address user = msg.sender;
    require(self.contributor[user].ether_in>0);
    ether_out = self.contributor[user].ether_in;
    self.numContributors--;
    user.transfer(ether_out);
    self.contributor[user].ether_in = 0
}
```

**Contact **

```
import './lib'
contract SimplifiedMainContract {

    using Lib for Lib.Store;
    Lib.Store private store;

    function deposit() public payable {
        store.deposit();
    }

    function withdraw() public {
        store.withdraw();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please share your (simplified) code

Comment: I know how to use SafeMath libery, I use it all the time... my issue is one user executing one function twice.

Comment: How are deposit and withdraw called? Perhaps you have a reentrancy attack, without an audit of the full code involved is hard to say anything.

Comment: just added the calling contract

Comment: @ismael To understand reentrancy attack just looked into https://medium.com/@gus_tavo_guim/reentrancy-attack-on-smart-contracts-how-to-identify-the-exploitable-and-an-example-of-an-attack-4470a2d8dfe4 . And if I understand correctly ... I dont think that the issue

Comment: Do you have the definitions for `Store`? Also how other types are declared like `contributor`, `ether_in`, `ether_out`.

Comment: "apparently if the user [tries] to execute [the withdraw] function [quickly] enough they can get the number of [contributors] all the way to [a] large number" To clarify, have you actually tried this and observed that happening? If so, please share how you're testing. (The code you've shared so far would not allow this.)

Answer (score 3):

You should google about overflowing/underflowing in variables and use [SafeMath](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol) library where such calculations are needed, since Solidity hasn't built-in checks for such things.

Comment: Thats not my problem, I am trying to avoid making such costly calculations for a prefectly contained environments.

Comment: also we can still go down from 2 conterbuters to 0 using math safe

Comment: math.sub(x,y) is not the answer to my question!

Comment: Umm it's clearly underflow issue here? You are not checking contributors count before subtracting, so subtracting from 0 will result in very high number. Unless your problem is not that you get such high number.

Comment: No its not! its definitely double execution problem, where one user can execute one function multiple times! clearly with mathsafe we cant got lower then 0 but user can still make the contract go from 100 to 97 if they execute function 3 times.

Comment: From the code you provided there is nothing stopping users to call function multiple times. There are no checks if user can or can't call it, why you expect it to fail after first attempt then?

Comment: Yeah i missed a line in (simplified) code

Comment: Ok so now you added check, but i still don't see where you deduct 
self.contributor[user].ether_in 
You only check value, but never deduct from it, so it's always the same.

Comment: just added the missing line to sample code, im still having double execution problem

Comment: This is weird, it should revert tx. Where are calling function from?

Comment: Thank you! what do you mean ? contract => library ... I mean anyone can call it im using web3 & metamask

Comment: Yes, i asked if you are using remix or web3. Strange then if this isn't working, i'm out of ideas.